# Troubles in annotation mapping hibernate with Spring MVC

Tags: java, hibernate, mapping, entities

Can someone please explain to me how to declare annotations on entities correctly?

There are two tables in the database. One table has a foreign key to a `id` of another one (`@ManyToOne` binding), both IDs are of `Integer`. And I created two entities to represent them in code.

**How can I map these entities to DB**? I had realized recently that Hibernate refers to classes. I mean that in `@JoinColumn("???")` I have to write the name of a column in DB, isn't it? What if the ID field's name in the entity is the same as in the DB? Thanks everyone in advance! Regards.

```java
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "stat")
    public class Statistic {

        @Id
        @Column( name = "statisticId")
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long statisticsId;
        ...............
        @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinColumn (name="userId") //<------------ The same name.
        private User userStat;

    //getters and setters + constr + overriding of ToString()
    }

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "usser")
    public class User {

        @Id
        @Column(name = "userId")
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long userId;`enter code here`

        ................

        @OneToOne(mappedBy = "userStat")
        private Statistic statisticUser;
    }
```

Comment: See [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-many-to-one)

Comment: Yes, JoinColumn expects the name of the... join column in the table. https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html#name--. *What if the ID field's name in the entity is the same as in the DB*: it's irrelevant.